# Can't get the AVG of the rows in the column

Tags: sql, average

I have a table with student's ID and there are their grades.
I need AVG grade in the other table as a column.

```
(SELECT Ocena
FROM Ocene
WHERE DjakID = '1')
```

Here is the code I used to SELECT grades I need. Tried to put AVG on some positions, but can't make it work.

Comment: `SELECT DjakID, AVG(Ocena) FROM Ocene GROUP BY DjakID` will give you the average grade by student. `SELECT AVG(Ocena) FROM Ocene` will give you the average grade of all the students.

Comment: *Why* can't you get it? What was your attempt? What is wrong with the [`AVG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function?

Comment: Also SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DjakID, AVG(Ocena) AS AvgGrade
FROM Ocene
WHERE DjakID = '1'
GROUP BY DjakID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped a lot. Even used it for the stored procedure for some UPDATEs!!!